# Problem with Exception.Cannot print exception string because Exception.ToString() failed

Tags: c#

I am currently practicing creating my Exception class. The idea of this code is for the user to enter a password. In case its code is less than 5 characters, the program will throw an exception. I want that my program throw one exception with text("Password is too small") and the object of my Exception class use ToString method(where will write " Password Length Exception").What confuses me is why I get the message Unhandled exception.Password Length exception. Cannot print exception string because Exception.ToString () failed. You can see this in the photo

[image]
Here is my code.

```
 public class My_Exception : Exception
    {
        
        public My_Exception(string message) : base(message)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(message);
        }
        
        public override string ToString()
        {
            throw new My_Exception(" Password Length exception ");
        }


    }



    class Program
    {
          
      static void Main(string[] args)
        
        {
           try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Enter your password");
                string Password = Console.ReadLine();
                if (Password.Length < 5)
                {
                   throw new My_Exception(" Password is too small ");
                }
            }

            catch(My_Exception ex)
            {

             Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: The error is pretty clear. `ToString()` is supposed to return a string containing all exception data instead of throw a new unrelated exception. If you don't want to add extra data, don't override `ToString()`.

Comment: Use the `message` in the constructor to pass the message. If you want to add extra data, use the `Exception.Data` dictionary

Comment: Use the `message` in the constructor to pass the message. If you want to add extra data, use the `Exception.Data` dictionary

Comment: As an aside, using exceptions here seems wrong. Exceptions should be used for *exceptional* flows. User input being wrong is hardly exceptional.

Answer (score 7):

Remove the override `.ToString().`

```
public class My_Exception : Exception
{        
    public My_Exception(string message) : base(message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(message);
    }       
}
```

The `message` will be shown by the base `Exception.ToString()`. You shouldn't thow an exception from another exception.

And in truth, you shouldn't `Console.WriteLine()` from inside the constructor of an `Exception`. It is the `try`/`catch` block that should print in any way it wants the exception.

```
public class My_Exception : Exception
{        
    public My_Exception(string message) : base(message)
    {
    }       
}
```

See running example at https://ideone.com/FchSGc

Comment: I'm sorry but I didn't understand you. I need to have Console.WriteLine inside the constructor because there is no other way to print the message specified within my constructor parameters

Comment: @SajoNezic Look at the ideone... The message is printed by the try/catch!

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

Don't throw an exception in the .ToString method. Return a string with information about what happened.

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return " Password Length exception ";
}
```

Or simply create a proper exception

```
public class PasswordToSmallException : Exception
{ 
    public PasswordToSmallException()
        : base("Password should be at least 5 characters")
    {}
}
```

And then you just

```
catch(Exception ex)
{ 
    Console.WriteLine(ex);
}
```

Comment: Even better, don't override `ToString()` at all. `Password Length Exception` should be a message

Answer (score -1):

Problem : cannot print exception string because exception.tostring() failed

Solution : I think it is a problem with the computer. I had this message also. I just restart the computer and it work.

Comment: Unlikely. Dis you read the other answers?